# ggplot pie chart from factor in single column

Tags: r, ggplot2, pie-chart

Hi I want to plot a pie chart with ggplot from a single column (male female percentage) of my data frame

The column contains eater the word male or female depending on the gender of the specimen.

I tried

```
ggplot(data_frame, aes(x="", y=factor(gender), fill=gender) + 
  geom_bar(width = 1, stat = "identity") + 
  coord_polar("y", start=0)
```

but i only get a white screen, is there a way to extract the pie chart without calculating the accumulated count of each gender in a separate list?

Comment: Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Comment: Try `ggplot(data_frame, aes(x="", fill=factor(gender)) + geom_bar(width = 1) + coord_polar("y", start=0)`.